# Reducing the width of a column and understanding css used

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, material-ui

I am looking at a react code with material UI and trying to understand
the className used like below.

Can you explain these two lines please? I thought you can only have a maximum of 12 columns.

```
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
```

I want to reduce the width of the Invoice covered and Reason for credit
which means reducing the width of the column. How can I achieve this?

```
            <div className="row customer-form-layout">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
                <div className="customer-form-details">
                <span>{this.props.customer.CustomerName}</span><br/>
                <span>Customer #: <b>{this.props.customer.biCustomerNumber }</b></span>                   
                </div>

                <div className="covered-section">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

                      <FormControl className="form-control">
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="invoice-number01" shrink>Invoice
                          Covered*</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                          value=''
                          inputProps={{
                            name: 'Test-number02',
                            id: 'Test-number02',
                          }}
                        >
                          <MenuItem value='1234567890'>1234567890</MenuItem>
                          <MenuItem value='2345678901'>2345678901</MenuItem>
                        </Select>

                      </FormControl>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <FormControl fullWidth className="form-control">
                  <InputLabel htmlFor="reason-field-value" shrink>Reason for Credit
                    </InputLabel>
                  <TextField
                    id="reason-field-value"
                    multiline
                    rows="8"
                    margin="normal"
                  />
                </FormControl>
              </div>
```

Comment: First of all, your component contains way too much information. Try to split your code into smaller components, that are easier to maintain. (For example, extract the details into it's own component). 

Regarding the cols: You can define different width for each viewport. `col-xs-12 col-sm-6` = 12 cols in viewport `xs`, 6 cols in viewport `sm`

Answer (score 1):

**For bootstrap 3**, a `col-xs-12` class means,  below `xs` (<768px), the element will take 12 columns.

While `col-sm-6`, means above `sm` (≥768px), it will take up 6 columns.

Therefore, this div

```
<div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
```

will take full width below 768px. However, when it reaches 768px and above, it will take 50% width.

Which also means, it is **completely equivalent** to this:

```
<div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
```

---

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-options

Comment: Great. How do I now reduce the width of this column?

Comment: A full 12-columns width would be the width of `.covered-section` div. Adjust the width of that class. Unless you can actually provide me with the CSS, or else I can't actually provide the exact solution.